# Отображение файлов директории WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем привет у меня написана та часть, которая просматривает директории и получает файлы которые там находятся, снизу пример класса который содержит это всё. У меня вопрос как мне отображать эти данные в TreeView или во что то похожее, причет поиск файлов происходит в отдельном потоке ,как понимаете элементы в нем обновляются. Я хочу что бы моё дерево динамически отрисовывалось.

```
class FileSystemNode : IEnumerable<FileSystemNode>
    {
        private List<FileSystemNode> nodes;

        public void Add(FileSystemNode node) => nodes.Add(node);

        public IEnumerable<FileSystemNode> FileSystemNodes
        {
            get
            {
                foreach (var node in nodes)
                    yield return node;
            }
        }
        public string Name { get => Path.GetFileName(FullPath); }

        public bool IsFile { get; set; }

        public string FullPath { get; set; }

        public FileSystemNode() => nodes = new List<FileSystemNode>();

        public bool HasFile
        {
            get => IsFile || nodes.Any(n => n.HasFile); 
        }

        public IEnumerator<FileSystemNode> GetEnumerator()
            => FileSystemNodes.Where(n => n.HasFile).GetEnumerator();

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            => GetEnumerator();

        public override string ToString()
            => string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) ? FullPath : Name;
    }
```

Comment: Чтобы что-то динамически обновлялось в интерфейсе из отображаемой коллекции, надо использовать `ObservableCollection`. Тогда при добавлении и удалении из нее элментов вы увидите изменения на экране автоматически.

Comment: не только там в FastTree который есть на WinForm без этого делают, просто не понимаю, как использовать ее в WPF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не нужно саму ноду делать `IEnumerable`, нода - это ячейка, элемент, она не коллекция, а коллекция - это дочерние ноды. Кстати при формировании логики дерева многие допускают эту ошибку, так что можно ее считать типовой и очень частой.

Берете `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```cs
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null) 
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Берете ноду

```cs
public class TreeNode : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _nodeName;
    private ObservableCollection<TreeNode> _items;

    public string NodeName
    {
        get => _nodeName; 
        set
        {
            _nodeName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TreeNode> Items
    {
        get => _items;
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Добавляете в View Model свойство

```cs
private ObservableCollection<TreeNode> _treeNodes;

public ObservableCollection<TreeNode> TreeNodes
{
    get => _treeNodes;
    set
    {
        _treeNodes = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

И вяжете в `TreeView`

```xml
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeNodes}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NodeName}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Всё, теперь добавляете в эту стуктуру полей и свойств по вкусу, дополняете разметку и готово - `TreeView` будет отслеживать все изменения в дереве автоматически.

---

Кстати, тип ноды можете обеспечить с помощью наследования

```cs
public class FileNode : TreeNode
{
   // ...
}

public class DirectoryNode : TreeNode
{
   // ...
}
```

Тогда для каждого типа ноды можно свою разметку будет замутить

```xml
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeNodes}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FileNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NodeName}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DirectoryNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NodeName,StringFormat=[{0}]}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Ну и как вы уже поняли, свойство `IsFile` больше не нужно. Просто добавляйте нужный тип ноды, а интерфейс подберет под него разметку.

```cs
node.Items.Add(new FileNode { NodeName = "file.txt" });
```

Comment: так попробую разобраться в этом, а кстати почему так надо делать ? (Тогда когда будет готовый резульат кину сюда ссылку на репозиторий)

Comment: @DanBit `кстати почему так надо делать ?` а как еще можно это сделать и при этом выжить?

Comment: @DanBit вот еще один [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61731042/12888024) из тех что я раньше писал, по сути про то же самое, только более подробный.

Comment: А меня ещё такой вопрос, я же буду осуществиять поиск по регулярному выражению ну например таких файлов *.txt как мне дальше логику организовывать (самого поиска и добавления) Получается же надо как-то убирать из дерева директории в которых нет файлов *txt

Comment: @DanBit вообще там все сложно. Есть `ICollectionView`, ее можно получить из коллекции `ICollectionView itemsView => CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Items);`, задать ей фильтр например `itemsView.Filter = item => item is TreeNode node && node.NodeName.Contains(FilterText)` и затем вызвать `itemsView.Refresh()`, и тогда `ObservableCollection` перефильтруется по указаннмоу фильтру. А сложность заключается в том, что этот механизм нужно будет прикрутить к каждой ноде. То есть чтобы вызвать `Refresh()`, нужно будет зайти в каждую ноду и вызвать или сделать это сеттере свойства ноды.

Comment: @DanBit делегат фильтра кстати можно задать один раз в конструкторе ноды, то есть не надо перезаписывать `Filter =` каждый раз. В общем, копать - туда. :)